# Using Rake on a gem with dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I have a gem that requires a 'Cms' namespace to be present when running.

However, when running rake tasks, nothing works as this Cms namespace isn't present. How do I get my rake tasks to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either, load your project source into the Rakefile (like Rails would do) or define a dummy module with the name Cms on your project.

```
# Rakefile
module Cms; end

task :my_task do
  # ..
end
```

If you are on rails, and this gem is a dependency, you just have to make your task dependent of the :environment rails' task.

```
# some_task.rake
task :my_task => :environment do
  # ..
end
```

Hope this helps.